# java.lang.NullPointerException error while executing SQL query inside try catch block

Tags: java, mysql, exception, nullpointerexception, try-catch

I get `java.lang.NullPointerException` error while running the program. Seems like the error appears to be inside the try block: 
`rs = st.executeQuery(query);` 
of the method `regcustomers` in the below Java code. Please review my code and help me understand what I have done wrong.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.vastika.serlvet.dao.ConnectionDb;

public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        // Read the data
        String name = req.getParameter("name");
        String email = req.getParameter("email");
        String line1 = req.getParameter("addressline1");
        String city = req.getParameter("city");
        String state = req.getParameter("state");
        String country = req.getParameter("country");
        String userid = req.getParameter("username");
        String password = req.getParameter("password");
        insertToDatabase(name, email, line1, city, state, country, userid,
                password);
        // Forward to Shopping page
        req.getRequestDispatcher("shop.html").forward(req, res);
    }

    private void insertToDatabase(String name, String email, String line1,
            String city, String state, String country, String userid,
            String password) {

        ConnectionDb con = new ConnectionDb();
        Statement st = con.makeConnection();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String query = "insert into regcustomers (Name, Email, Address, City, State, Country, Username, Password) values("+"'"+name+"'"+","+"'"+email+"'"+","+"'"+line1+"'"+","+"'"+city+"'"+","+"'"+state+"'"+","+"'"+country+"'"+","+"'"+userid+"'"+","+"'"+password+"'"+");";

        System.out.println(query);

        try {
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            System.out.println(rs.getRow());
            } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        
            }

    }
}
```

and

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConnectionDb {
    public Statement makeConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement st = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onlineshopping", "root",
                    "test");
            st = conn.createStatement();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        return st;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `con.makeConnection()` do?

Comment: what is your con.makeConnection() doing? please post all relevant code if possible.

Comment: And make sure that the exception blames the line that you assume has the problem. Adding the exception would be nice (and point the lines).

Comment: A note: SQL tables should always be singular. You should change `regcustomers` to `regcustomer`.

Comment: Quick comment: Research about parametized arguments. Your code seems vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, con.makeConnection() creates Statement after establishing connection.

Comment: Also, please don't add code or other major details in the comments; instead, [edit] the question.

Answer (score 3):

What's happenning is that you are getting an exception in the following code

```
public Statement makeConnection() {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement st = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/onlineshopping", "root",
                "test");
        st = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getStackTrace();
    }
    return st;
}
```

and then return `st` which is `null` because the code never got to `conn.createStatement()`.

You're not actually printing the `Exception` by the way. Use `e.printStackTrace()`.

Also you should actually handle the exception.

Comment: I printed the Exception using e.printStackTrace(), and it is still not working. Seems like the code works fine until it goes to the point inside the try block (rs = st.executeQuery(query); which means that the makeConnection seems to be working. But not yet sure whats causing it to Null Pointer Exception.

Comment: My answer explains it, because of the exception your `makeConnection()` is returning `null`. What exception does it show?

Comment: This is wat the Console appeared:

Comment: SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [RegistrationServlet] in context with path [/OnlineShopping] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.vastika.servlets.RegistrationServlet.insertToDatabase(RegistrationServlet.java:51)

Comment: @prince2369 That's the NPE. What does the exception caught in `makeConnection()` say?

Comment: the Excpetion does not refer to the makeConnection() method. I was not able to get exception in this method. I will post if I see it.

Answer (score 0):

need not to put semicolon `;`

```
String query = "insert into regcustomers (Name, Email, Address, City, State, Country, Username, Password) values("+"'"+name+"'"+","+"'"+email+"'"+","+"'"+line1+"'"+","+"'"+city+"'"+","+"'"+state+"'"+","+"'"+country+"'"+","+"'"+userid+"'"+","+"'"+password+"'"+")";
```

it ll return `ResultSet` when you ll hit `SELECT` query

remove that `ResultSet` declaration..

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DATABASENAME", "root", "");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
```

use `int count = st.executeUpdate();`

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this:

```
private void insertToDatabase(String name, String email, String line1,
            String city, String state, String country, String userid,
            String password) {

        ConnectionDb con = new ConnectionDb();
        Statement st = con.makeConnection();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        String query = "insert into regcustomers (Name, Email, Address, City, State, Country, Username, Password) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        st.setString(1,name);
        st.setString(2,email);
        st.setString(3,line1);
        st.setString(4,street);
        st.setString(5,state);
        st.setString(6,country);
        st.setString(7,userid);
        st.setString(8,passwoname);

        try {
            int flag = st.executeUpdate(query);
            } 
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();        
            }

    }
```

I think what you wannna do is not a query, is more an update. So instead of:

```
rs = st.executeQuery(query);
```

You can do something like:

```
int flag = st.executeUpdate(query);
```

See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29) to have more info.

Att: u are having  a NullPointer Exception because(maybe) `rs = st.executeQuery(query);` retrieve nothing.

Hope it helps ^^

Comment: I can not use setString since it is undefined for Statement type. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Sorry, instead of `Statment` u can use `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @Cold  executeQuery(query) can never return null, hence it will not cause NullPointerException. [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery()) ref

Answer (score 0):

There is a strange situation when java.lang.NullPointerException error is triggered while executing SQL query inside try catch block.
The query updates selected index in several JComboboxes.
These JComboboxes are initially linked to update manually indexes according to a shema:

```
private void PriorityLoad6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        NewSelectedIndex = PriorityLoad6.getSelectedIndex(); SetNewIndexes();
    }
```

In this situation, when performing mysql update with a simple

```
PriorityLoad6.setSelectedIndex(rs.getInt("PriorityLoad_6"));
```

the above mentioned error is triggered.
In this situation one solution is to "isolate" the code inside with an if which is not active during query. For example:

```
private void PriorityLoad6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
                if (SaveSettings.hasFocus() == false){NewSelectedIndex = PriorityLoad6.getSelectedIndex(); SetNewIndexes();}}
```

This action should be of course preceded by adequately placed:

```
SaveSettings.requestFocus();
```

before calling the mysql query.